# How is interacting with a prompt of a third party command line program different from a Windows Command prompt?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, command-line, command-prompt

I was recently trying to make a Swing GUI to send and receive commands from a third party command line [program](http://urjtag.org/). I used the same procedure as used and working for Command Prompt, i.e., `ProcessBuilder` class to execute and then used BufferedReader to read responses from the program. I can surely mention it again that I could read some response, at least, from the Windows command prompt(sometimes I needed to use a Scanner in stead). When I used the same on [this](http://urjtag.org/) command line program,

1. It didn't show up
2. It didn't respond to either BufferedReader or Scanner.

   I searched the internet and found a monotonous reply from it that executing the same procedure on them both is not the same thing because they are not the same things. I have not been able to complete my project till now, but I can sleep a little more at ease if I get to know what is the difference between them, their execution, aren't they same, is there any way in which we can actually bring them together and that my problem can be solved?

Comment: Not a question so far: "why a program does not use standard input or standard output" is not really useful/answerable. There are also many reasons why a program will not start... First thing to try would be to pipe input/output to/from that program in command prompt to see if it indeed reads input...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov sir, I don't have the reputation to vote up your comment, but thank you and I was myself feeling the need to reframe the question.

Comment: @SukhmeetSingh At first glance I'd say that the program most likely opens its own shell, thous the "original" shell remains silent and non-responsive. Please describe the behavior of the program when you execute it manually from your shell.

Comment: @SukhmeetSingh Also, having looked at the code it behaves differently if you have readline on your system available. Do you?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer sir, when I execute it manually from shell it would take over the prompt and a prompt of its own appears after some discription of the software. The prompt looks like `jatg>`. I do have readLine available on my system.

Comment: @SukhmeetSingh rethinking my comment under Rajeshs answer: Do you want to call a java program that itself then calls the CLI of the UrJTAG Library?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer, no sir my Swing GUI application itself calls that CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the program starts its own shell and does no longer interact with the original one. (You would notice this if the program opens a new window)

Or the program needs some specific library to be present to be able to interact with a shell ([readline](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/readline/info) seems to be the case here) and that is not present in your Java Environment.

As a quick hack you might try to start `bash` (or `cmd`) that then starts the tool. `bash` and `cmd` have `readline` library. I don't have a windows ready here but as a guess just try to call your program like `cmd urjtag.exe` instead of just `urjtag.exe` that way you start a `cmd` process (with that you can interact) and that `cmd` starts the `urjtag.exe` where you already know that it can interact with.

Either way the problem lies in the way the program you want to call interacts with the shell and you should ask the authors of the program how it does and how you can connect to it.

Comment: sir, I think you are right because when I execute the exe it would take over the prompt, although not in a different window, but yes it does seem to have started its own procesure and then, but of course, no windows command like dir/p would work. I will be happy to look into the `bash` and see if it can help. Again my reputation doesn't allow me to vote your answer up. (PS : The readline link has no page sir)

Comment: @SukhmeetSingh I fixed the link. bash is a linux / unix tool. I'm unsure if it exists or is available on windows.

Comment: @SukhmeetSingh I added information regarding `cmd` instead of `bash`. have a look.

Comment: sir thank you, I had no idea about bash(since always been working on windows) and the search results were also saying the same. I think I didn't read your answer carefully.

Comment: @SukhmeetSingh You're welcome. Also, welcome on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

From the UrJTAG documentation:

> JTAG (IEEE 1149.1) is a serial interface for testing devices with
>   integrated circuits.

and

> UrJTAG is a software package which enables working with JTAG-aware
>   (IEEE 1149.1) hardware devices (parts) and boards through a JTAG
>   adapter.

1. It is not a command prompt.
2. It is not meant to be used as a command prompt for generic programs.

So, as other monotonous responses have already told you, it and the windows command prompt are not the same thing, even though you seem to think they are. It has a very specific use-case as described in the documentation.

The windows command prompt is a special program which invokes specific executables and passes command line arguments to them in a specific way.

The `java.exe` executable is designed to understand this kind of invocation.

Since the UrJTAG executable it is not a generic command prompt, it doesn't do what the windows command prompt does, and so will not work for running Java programs like you want.

Comment: As far as I understood the OP he wants to start the command line interface of a specific JTAG library. The start happens to be from java and he wants to interact with that CLI via std-in and std-out. That is an expected and supported use case. (not of JTAG in general but of this library)

Comment: Reasonable assumption. I'll wait till OP provides some clarity and delete my response if what you say is confirmed.

Comment: @RajeshJAdvani sir I have stopped thinking anything either way now and have become impartial, if that helps. I never said that it is a command prompt sir, it is, although, undoubtedly a command-line program. I agree that java.exe should have been designed to interact with cmd, but what bewilders me is that when the software takes over the prompt from the windows command prompt in the same window, why can't we read from that?

Comment: Because it's not a generic prompt.